# Custom error "on" throwing error on every button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am facing a very strange issue. When the customError property in web.config is set "On" then every post back on a particular page is throwing an error. Where as if I set it to "Off" then same post backs (Button clicks, dropdown change events) are working as expected.

Can any please throw some light what can be the reason.

Comment: What kind of error did it throw?

Comment: You just check the proper error ! Put a break point and verify what exactly happening in your code.

Comment: Wen trying to run in local everything is running good. There is no error logged in log file. If its "On" then it is showing error page if "off" then its working. So that is why not able to catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines of code in your `Global.asax.cs`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
...
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 
    }
...
}
```

And make sure this is calling during `application_start`

Comment: My application is asp.net application